# Obtaining Input DDName from FTP (JES)

Tags: ftp, mainframe, zos, jcl, mvs

I have a job in JES on the mainframe that I want to retrieve or list directory via FTP.

I'm able to do so easily if I want one or all of the OUTPUT DDNames of my job
(In SDSF, with "INPUT OFF" command)

```
SDSF JOB DATA SET DISPLAY - JOB MYUSERUL (JOB06197)    LINE 1-8 (8)
COMMAND INPUT ===>                                            SCROLL ===> PAGE
PREFIX=*  DEST=(ALL)  OWNER=*  SYSNAME=
NP   DDNAME   StepName ProcStep DSID Owner    C Dest               Rec-Cnt Page
     JESMSGLG JES2                 2 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   16
     JESJCL   JES2                 3 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   74
     JESYSMSG JES2                 4 MYUSER   X LOCAL                  152
     FILESEQ  ETAPE010           103 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   10
     PRINT    ETAPE010           104 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   17
     IMPRIM   ETAPE020           107 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   28
     LISTUTV  ETAPE020           110 MYUSER   X LOCAL                    2
     LISTE    ETAPE020           111 MYUSER   X LOCAL                    4
```

To do so, I execute a DIR command and then a GET command With the DDName id.

```
ftp> dir j06197
200 Port request OK.
125 List started OK for JESJOBNAME=MYUSER*, JESSTATUS=ALL and JESOWNER=MYUSER
JOBNAME  JOBID    OWNER    STATUS CLASS
MYUSERUL JOB06197 MYUSER   OUTPUT T        RC=0000
--------
         ID  STEPNAME PROCSTEP C DDNAME   BYTE-COUNT
         001 JES2              X JESMSGLG       688
         002 JES2              X JESJCL        2735
         003 JES2              X JESYSMSG      9553
         004 ETAPE010          X FILESEQ        244
         005 ETAPE010          X PRINT         1116
         006 ETAPE020          X IMPRIM        3504
         007 ETAPE020          X LISTUTV        173
         008 ETAPE020          X LISTE          248
8 spool files
250 List completed successfully.
ftp> get j06197.1 D:\test.txt
```

Unfortunately, the information i'm seeking is in the INPUT DDNames
(In SDSF, with "INPUT ON" command)

```
SDSF JOB DATA SET DISPLAY - JOB MYUSERUL (JOB06197)    LINE 1-13 (13)
COMMAND INPUT ===>                                            SCROLL ===> PAGE
PREFIX=*  DEST=(ALL)  OWNER=*  SYSNAME=
NP   DDNAME   StepName ProcStep DSID Owner    C Dest               Rec-Cnt Page
     JESJCLIN                      1 MYUSER   X                         55
     JESMSGLG JES2                 2 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   16
     JESJCL   JES2                 3 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   74
     JESYSMSG JES2                 4 MYUSER   X LOCAL                  152
     $INTTEXT JES2                 5 MYUSER   A                         25
     $JOURNAL                      6 MYUSER   A                        175
     FICIN    ETAPE010           101 MYUSER   X                          3
     CARTE    ETAPE020           102 MYUSER   X                          2
     FILESEQ  ETAPE010           103 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   10
     PRINT    ETAPE010           104 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   17
     IMPRIM   ETAPE020           107 MYUSER   X LOCAL                   28
     LISTUTV  ETAPE020           110 MYUSER   X LOCAL                    2
     LISTE    ETAPE020           111 MYUSER   X LOCAL                    4
```

How can I retrieve one of the INPUT DDName via FTP (Ex: the "JESJCLIN")
Is there a way to se INPUT DDNames via the DIR command too ?

**UPDATE**

Utimate goal is, for example, resubmiting a job from FTP. For this I need the initial JCL and also everything "inline", both only accessible using "INPUT ON"

I'm in no way talking about Production jobs. I'm talking about a programmer's job (or a "Testing job") that was submitted manually on the mainframe by the programmer, and I would like it to be possible for that same programmer to access the full INPUT information of the submitted job via an external PC tool, including submitted JCL with also content of inline DDs, to eventually do something with it, one example use case (but not the only one) would be to resubmit the same exact job.

Thanks !

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you want to see? What is the JESINTERFACELEVEL at your site (with 1 I'd say for sure No, with 2 it may depend)? Anyway, even if JESINTERFACELEVEL 2 may let you do this, there is additional security involved which may be preventing you (or it may not be possible). You need to talk to your technical staff.

Comment: Utimate goal is for example, resubmit a job from FTP. For thisI need the initial JCL and also everything "inline", both only accessible using "INPUT ON"

Comment: Oh and JESINTERFACELEVEL is 2

Comment: Where was it submitted from first? Are you talking about Production, or something for testing? For Production, use your Scheduler. You need to contact your technical support. The documentation is not clear for 2 if you may be able to do it (you for sure can't for 1). You need to update your question with detail of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: **WARNING** if you are talking about a production job and that job is managed through a scheduler, then if you submit a job with the same job name then some schedulers may consider that as the actual production job, see it complete and continue scheduling as if the real production job had completed.

Comment: I did not know this information was relevant, but i'm in no way talking about Production jobs. I'm talking about a programmer's job (so what you call a "Testing job") that was submitted manually on the mainframe by the programmer, and I would like it to be possible for that same programmer to access the full INPUT information of the submitted job via an external PC tool, including submitted JCL with also content of inline DDs, to eventually do something with it, one example use case (but not the only one) would be to resubmit the same exact job. I'm gonna update the question with this info !

Comment: You must talk to your technical staff, as I said. The documentation is unclear on whether you can do this potentially with 2. It may be not possible, or it may be something within the security policy of your site. You may get somewhere (in determining potential) by looking at the Rexx-SDSF documentation. Remember. If your site knowingly doesn't want you to do this it will be a bad idea to try on your own.

Comment: I don't quite get the workflow. If the submitted the job initially form the Mainframe, why can't they just do that again? You may also consider the Rational Developer documentation. If a similar facility is available there, then again it would be a strong indicator that you are limited, perhaps not knowingly, by your site security policy.